About ApexBatch Validation with REST API
The purpose of this validation is to execute a Salesforce REST from an external system and an Apex batch from an external system.
The REST API validation displayed the following error.

"error": "invalid_grant",.
" error_description": "Authentication failed.
}

User ID, password, security token reissued, etc.
I have verified this many times and there is no problem.
What other possible causes are there?
Parameters used for verification

HEADERS

Content-Type：application/x-www-form-urlencoded


BODY

grant_type  ：password
client_id   ：Secret key　
client_secret：Consumer Key
username    ：Salesforce login User
password    ：Salesforce login Password




The username-password flow is not recommended and is disabled by default for orgs/sandboxes/scratch orgs made on/after Summer '23 (API v58.0). If this process is headless (i.e. you can't show a screen to the user for them to enter their credentials, machine-to-machine communication) then the Client Credentials flow is probably what you should be using.

The JWT Bearer Flow is also a headless option, and would give you the option to act on behalf of more than just a single, configured user (which is the case for the client credentials flow).

Thanks for the advice.
I will take this advice as a hint to deepen my knowledge.
